# Reddit api session cookie format?

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, request, reddit

I'm trying to use reddit api to login with a bot using node.js and request.js. I've managed to figure out that I need both the modhash and the session cookie that are returned from the /api/login request. I have accessed both with the following code:

```
    request.post({
        uri: 'http://www.reddit.com/api/login',
        json: true,
        headers: agentheader,
        qs : logincreds
    },function(err,response,body){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        } else {
            if(response.statusCode == 200){
                mhash = body.json.data.modhash;
                session_cookie = body.json.data.cookie;
                console.log(body.json.data.cookie);
                console.log("login OK, modhash: "+mhash);
                console.log("Session cookie: "+session_cookie);
                agentheader = {
                    'user-agent': 'base10bot made by /u/01011110',
                    'X-Modhash' : mhash,
                    'Cookie' : 'reddit_session='+session_cookie
                };
    ...
```

and in that last bit I set the custom headers with the modhash and the cookie in the way that someone on /r/redditdev told me it should be done. The session cookie doesn't work at all without the "reddit_session=" part, but with it everything I do returns a 403 forbidden.

I'm pretty sure the "cookie" is formatted wrong because when I log it, it shows up as a numerical id, a time-stamp, and a hash all comma delimited. Can someone help me figure out the right way to send this cookie header? Everything I find on google is either using python requests or bash.

Comment: Try removing "bot" from your user-agent. I recall having problems with that in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not parsing body as JSON. Try this -

```
data = JSON.parse(body);
session_cookie = data.json.data.cookie;
```